# How to fix pushSubscription is null on firebase messaging on mobile browsers?

Tags: firebase, firefox, mobile, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get Firebase Cloud Messaging to work on mobile browsers for my site but keep running into issues retrieving the device token as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token). My site is built in Angular and is being served over HTTPS on a real domain and the relevant FCM code is basically:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/messaging";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({...});
const messaging = firebase.messaging(app);
messaging.getToken({vapidKey: '...'})
    .then((token) => {
      console.log('got token: ', token);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
```

This works fine on desktop browsers and on Chrome on mobile, but I haven't been able to get it to work on Firefox on Android with the latest Firefox. It does correctly request the notification permission but then just throws an error from within the Firebase libs due to a seemingly empty value:

```js
TypeError: pushSubscription is null
    getToken index.esm.js:632
    step tslib.es6.js:102
    verb tslib.es6.js:83
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:73
    Angular 21
    promisifyRequest idb.js:13
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    promisifyRequest idb.js:12
    p idb.js:27
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    promisifyRequestCall idb.js:25
    deleteDb idb.js:308
    migrateOldDatabase index.esm.js:268
    step tslib.es6.js:102
    verb tslib.es6.js:83
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:73
    Angular 21
    promisifyRequest idb.js:13
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    promisifyRequest idb.js:12
    p idb.js:27
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    promisifyRequestCall idb.js:25
    deleteDb idb.js:308
    migrateOldDatabase index.esm.js:265
    step tslib.es6.js:102
    verb tslib.es6.js:83
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:73
    Angular 11
```

Firefox debug shows the lib code as:

```js
function getToken(firebaseDependencies, swRegistration, vapidKey) {
    return Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["__awaiter"])(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var pushSubscription, tokenDetails, subscriptionOptions, e_1;
        return Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["__generator"])(this, function (_a) {
            switch (_a.label) {
                case 0:
                    if (Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
                        throw ERROR_FACTORY.create("permission-blocked" /* PERMISSION_BLOCKED */);
                    }
                    return [4 /*yield*/, getPushSubscription(swRegistration, vapidKey)];
                case 1:
                    pushSubscription = _a.sent();
                    return [4 /*yield*/, dbGet(firebaseDependencies)];
                case 2:
                    tokenDetails = _a.sent();
                    subscriptionOptions = {
                        vapidKey: vapidKey,
                        swScope: swRegistration.scope,
                        endpoint: pushSubscription.endpoint, // pushSubscription is null
                        auth: arrayToBase64(pushSubscription.getKey('auth')),
                        p256dh: arrayToBase64(pushSubscription.getKey('p256dh'))
                    };
```

I can see that on desktop there are network calls from the lib to Google APIS to send information like installation and registration as well as creating an installation DB that don't happen on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with other ways to subscribe I think the issue is actually with Firefox on Android not correctly generating the subscription. Debugging the Firefox Main Process on a desktop I can see a call to updates.push.services.mozilla.com that returns a 410 that seems to suggest that the device no longer has an endpoint to use. Wiping the app's data (in the Android settings, not just clearing browsing data) forces it to regenerate one and after that it works.

This is apparently a known issue: https://github.com/mozilla-services/autopush/issues/1445
that doesn't have a fix other than to do the factory reset of the app. I was just unlucky enough to have 2 devices that are both affected by this bug.